# useReducer state returns undefined (React)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components

my functional component has a useReducer state and it has two inputs, the inputs values are set to the state object and state works perfect in first render however when I change the inputs web page crashes and console error says cannot read value of undefined
here's the code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useReducer } from "react";
import Card from "../UI/Card-Wrap/Card";
const Login = () => {
  const reducer = (state, action) => {
    if (action.id === "username") {
      state.username = action.value;
    }

    if (action.id === "password") {
      state.password = action.value;
    }
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    username: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    dispatch(e.target);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Card>
        <form action="#" className={Styles.form}>
          <p>Login</p>
          <div className={Styles.username}>
            <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="username"
              onChange={onChangeHandler}
              value={state.username}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={Styles.password}>
            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              id="password"
              onChange={onChangeHandler}
              value={state.password}

            />
          </div>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

I've tried to find where it happens on every render apparently it happens every time i set state value in Reducer function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is happening because your reducer function is not **returning the new  state.**

This causes the state to be `undefined` after you dispatch the action and then the `cannot read value of undefined` error is raised at the input `value` attribute.

As per [React Documentation](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useReducer#writing-the-reducer-function):

> State is read-only. Don’t modify any objects or arrays in state:
>
> ```js
> function reducer(state, action) {   switch (action.type) {
>     case 'incremented_age': {
>       //  Don't mutate an object in state like this:
>       state.age = state.age + 1;
>       return state;
>     }
> ```
>
> Instead, always return new objects from your reducer:
>
> ```js
> function reducer(state, action) {   switch (action.type) {
>     case 'incremented_age': {
>       // ✅ Instead, return a new object
>       return {
>         ...state,
>         age: state.age + 1
>       };
>     }
> ```

Please note that besides returning the state, it should be a **new object.**
You should not change values in the current state object, as objects in JS are treated as **references** and by returning the same state object, **React would not re-render your component.**

So, a solution for the problem could be rewriting the reducer function as following:

```js
  const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.id) {
      case "username":
        return {
          ...state,               // Spreads the current state into a new object
          username: action.value, // and changes only the desired value
        };
      case "password":
        return {
          ...state,
          password: action.value,
        };
      default:
        return { ...state };
    }
  };
```